# Calculations in a query joining 2 table Mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

I am trying to determine how to do sum nd subtract fields between two tables.

In table 1(com_payments), I would have, for example, tender_id, amount

In table 2(process), I would have , for example, tender_id, lc_amt_value

I want to take and sum the amount from com_payments (sumofamount) First where main_section = supplier

Then with that sumofamount i need to substract lc_amt_value (table process) where com_payments.tenderid=process.tender_id (TotalAmount)

```
Table example:

    com_payments
    ----------------------------------
    tender_id | amount     | main_section
    ----------------------------------
    |      1  | 300.00     |  supplier
    |      1  | 200.989    |  customer
    |      1  | 2300.900   |  supplier
    ----------------------------------

    process
    ----------------------------
    tender_id | lc_amt_value
    ----------------------------
    |   1 |        50.00
    |   2 |        126.00
    |   3 |        50.00
    ----------------------------


The results that I *want* are

    TOTALS
    ------------------------------------------
    | tender_id | sumofamount | TotalAmount 
    ------------------------------------------
    | 1         |  2600.900   |   2550.900 
    ------------------------------------------
```

1) First Need to do the sum of 'amount' (sumofamount) from table com_payments where main_section='supplier' 
2) Secondly from sumofamount i need to substract lc_amt_value from table process (comparison is tender_id)

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS  sumofamount 
FROM com_payments vg
LEFT JOIN process f
select (f.lc_amt_value - sumofamount) As TotalAmount
ON f.tender_id = vg.tender_id
```

Iam not getting any output. Anyone to pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT vg.tender_id, 
       sum(amount) as sumofamount, 
       sum(amount) - lc_amt_value as totalamount
FROM com_payments as vg
JOIN (SELECT tender_id, sum(lc_amt_value) as lc_amt_value
      FROM process
      GROUP BY tender_id
) as t on vg.tender_id = t.tender_id
GROUP BY tender_id
```

Comment: Am getting this error: Column 'tender_id' in field list is ambiguous